# Kubernetes relation between worker node IP address and Pod IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two questions.

1. All the tutorials in the youtube says that, if the worker node internal IP is 10.10.1.0 then the pods inside the node will have internal IPs between 10.10.1.1 till 10.10.1 254. But in my Google Kubernetes Engine it is very different and I don't see any relation between them.

   rc-server-1x769 ip is 10.0.0.8 but its corresponding node gke-kubia-default-pool-6f6eb62a-qv25 has 10.160.0.7

[image]

2. How to release the external ips assigned to my worker nodes.

Comment: Pod ips get assigned by the deployed CNF plugin and the configured pod cidr range. it does not  necessarily correspond to your nodes internal-ips. see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/ for further information

Comment: How about releasing the ip addresses of the nodes?

Comment: I believe you don't want to do so. But if you insist you can try to cordon-drain-uncordon nodes and see if it'll help.

Comment: Any specific reason for releasing external IPs of the nodes ? If you prefer that your nodes don't have external IP addresses, simply create a [private cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept).

Answer (score 1):

Pod's CIDR and Cluster CIDR - it's different entities.
So Pod-Pod communication happens within Pod's CIDR, not within cluster CIDR.
Your nodes should have interfaces, which corresponds to your Pods CIDR. But from Cluster point of view, they have Cluster IP's. (kubectl output)

Answer (score 0):

For Q2:

GKE manages the VMs created in your cluster so if they go down or if there needs to be down/up scaling, VMs are created with the same characteristics. I do not believe what you are asking is possible (release). You will need to consider a [private cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters).